# Why is the last x-axis label omitted?

Tags: r, plot

In the following example, the last x-axis label ("4.0") is omitted.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3.8), y = c(1, 2, 3))
#png(filename = "cutoff.png")
plot(df$x, df$y, xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 4, 0.5), labels = seq(0, 4, 0.5))
#dev.off()
```

How to prevent this behaviour?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You axis limit does not include 4; you need to overwrite the default limits of the plot (which it derives from the data) using `xlim`:

```
plot(df$x, df$y, xaxt = "n", xlim = c(1, 4))
```

[image]

*Note that when using `axis` your specification of `at` will become your `labels` unless you overwrite that, so your script doesn't need to specify `labels`; your script can become:*

```
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 4, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @griffinevo answered (+1), If you want the axis limits to go to 4, you must specify that using `xlim`. However, it is probably worth explaining how the default limits are computed. This is explained in the documentation, but in a slightly obscure place. On the help page `?par`  search for `xaxs`. There you will see

> Style "r" (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each
>   end and then finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the
>   extended range.

In your case, the data ranges from 1 to 3.8. So plot will look for pretty labels inside the range

```
1 - 0.04*(3.8-1) = 0.888   
    to 
3.8 + 0.04*(3.8-1) = 3.912
```

4 is outside of this range and so will not appear as an axis label. For completeness, it is worth noting that "pretty" sounds like just a word, but actually has a technical meaning here - related to the `pretty` function. If you look at the help page `?pretty` You will see the description:

> Compute a sequence of about n+1 equally spaced ‘round’ values which
>   cover the range of the values in x. The values are chosen so that they
>   are 1, 2 or 5 times a power of 10.

There is additional detail on the help page.